# Shortcut methods

Tags: java, frameworks

My original question was quite incorrect, I have classes (not [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)), which have shortcut methods for business logic classes, to give the consumer of my API the ability to use it like:

```
Connector connector = new ConnectorImpl();
Entity entity = new Entity(connector);
entity.createProperty("propertyName", propertyValue);
entity.close;
```

Instead of:

```
Connector connector = new ConnectorImpl();
Entity entity = new Entity();
connector.createEntityProperty(entity, "propertyName", propertyValue);
connector.closeEntity(entity);
```

Is it good practice to create such shortcut methods?

#### Old question

At the moment I am developing a small framework and have a pretty nice separation of the business logic in different classes (connectors, authentication tokens, etc.), but one thing is still bothers me. I have methods which manipulates with POJOs, like this:

```
public class BuisnessLogicImpl implements BusinessLogic{
    public void closeEntity(Entity entity) {
        // Business Logic
    }
}
```

And POJO entities which also have a close method:

```
public class Entity {
    public void close(){
        businessLogic.closeEntity(this);    
    }
}
```

Is it good practice to provide two ways to do the same thing? Or better, just remove all "proxy" methods from POJOs for clarity sake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the methods from the "POJOs"... They aren't really POJO's if you encapsulate functionality like this. The reason for this comes from [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) design principles which basically says you want [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) between the different layers of your application.

If you are familiar with [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) containers, like [Google_Guice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guice) or [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)-- this separation is a requirement. For instance, let's say you have a `CreditCard` POJO and a `CreditCardProcessor` service, and a `DebugCreditCardProcess` service that doesn't actually charge the CC money (for testing).

```
@Inject
private CardProcessor processor;

...

CreditCard card = new CreditCard(...params...);
processor.process(card);
```

In my example, I am relying on an IoC container to provide me with a `CardProcessor`. Whether this is the debug one, or the real one... I don't really care and neither does the `CreditCard` object. The one that is provided is decided by your application configuration.

If you had coupling between the processor and credit card where I could say `card.process()`, you would always have to pass in the `processor` in the card constructor. `CreditCards` can be used for other things besides processing however. Perhaps you just want to load a `CreditCard` from the database and get the expiration date... It shouldn't need a processor to do this simple operation.

You may argue: "The credit card could get the processor from a static factory". While true, [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) are widely regarded as an anti-pattern requiring keeping a global state in your application.

Keeping your business logic separate from your data model is always a good thing to do to reduce the coupling required. Loose coupling makes testing easier, and it makes your code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, it exactly the thing i was woried about. I will remove all shortcuts and refactor code to get rid of the passing buisnessLogic object to the POJO (or fake POJO in my case).

Comment: IIRC, loose coupling means that you should pass object as instances of an interface rather than a class so the implementation may be easily changed. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your case as "two methods", because the logic of the implementation is kept in bussinessLogic. It would be akin of asking if it is a good idea `java.lang.System` has both a method `getProperties()` and a `getProperty(String)`, more than a different method is just a shortcut to the same method.

But, in general, no, it is not good practice. Mainly because:

a) if the way to do that thing changes in the future, you need to remember that you have to touch two implementations.

b) when reading your code, other programmers will wonder if there are two methods because they are different.

Also, it does not fit very well with assigning responsabilities to a specific class for a given task, which is one of the tenets of OOP.

Of course, all absolute rules may have a special case where some considerations (mainly performance) may suggest breaking the rule. Think if you win something by doing so and document it heavily.